# Pygame; making C extensions

Tags: python, c, optimization, pygame

I'm relatively new to python and have made some useful tools and some small games w/ 10 sprites in python; based on performance I think my next logical step is making C extensions to improve performance in pygame.

My first initial question is in pygame, can I make a main loop in C (or would I have to interface with SDL?). And sprites, could I make C code that strictly handles the sprites, and only use python for scripting purposes of the game?

Comment: If it runs fast enough, you don't need to rewrite part of it in C. In fact, it would propably be counter-productive.

Comment: I would actually disagree as my friend has made a breakout variant among other games that only get 10-15 fps because of "sprites" in pygame

Answer (score 3):

Without any insight to your code, I can make these suggestions.  Since you are rightly concerned about performance, instead of trying to improve performance by writing C modules, try optimising the python code you have written.  A good article on how to do this can be found in this [article about patterns at Python.org](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str).

To answer your question about the main loop, it depends on what you mean by a main loop.  Do you mean `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or are you talking about `SDL_main`?

You can create a C program which runs python for scripting purposes.  You can run it as a python script, which run C modules for extra performance.  I don't know if you can mix and match using SDL in python and also in C, but don't see why it wouldn't work, but I haven't tried doing it.